# Reconnect MongoDB using MongoSkin ( Nodejs )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I have been using MongoSkin( Nodejs ) plugin to connect Mongodb as below.

```
    var db = mongo.db(dbconfig.mongo_ip+'/'+dbconfig.mongo_db_name);
    db.collection('myprofile').findOne({_id:memberid}, function(err, session){

        if(err){
            db.close();
            console.log(err.stack);
        }

    })
```

If i got the mongo connection error from node.js, then how do i reconnect the same using mongoskin,

```
Mongo Connect errr: Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:184:51)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:45:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:110:14)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:45:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoskin/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:301:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:42:17)
    at Array.33 (net.js:799:27)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:108:26)
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is

https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/blob/master/test/db.js

but I assume you need to call open on db under mongoskin as well as in the driver.